# How to do python meta programming to pass code blocks around (like ruby yield)

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

Like ruby, how to pass code block and get it executed (yield) where you pass it. I am trying to achieve same thing in python 3.5
This is what my pseudo code looks like. How to achieve what I am trying to do. What changes would I have to make?

```
# Calculate all
# I want this function should yield whatever method passed to it

# THIS MUST BE A CLASS
class Calculator:

  def __init__(self):
    self.prefix = "hello"

  def calculate(self, function_name)
    local_val = 10
    print("executing {} function with {}".format(function_name, self.prefix))
    result = function_name(local_val)
    print(result)
    return result



# I want to pass these functions to Calculator().calculate() method

def add_one(x):
  return x+1

def minus_one(x):
  return x-1

def divide_in_half(x):
  return x/2



Calculator().calculate(add_one(?))
# expect this to print:
# executing add_one function with hello
# 11


Calculator().calculate(minus_one(?))
# expect this to print:
# executing minus_one function with hello
# 9

Calculator().calculate(divide_in_half(?))
# expect this to print:
# executing divide_in_half function with hello
# 5
```

Comment: It sounds like your `Calculator` doesn't need to be a class at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are objects in Python, so you can just do this:

```
Calculator().calculate(add_one)
Calculator().calculate(minus_one)
Calculator().calculate(divide_in_half)
```

Note that this passes *the function itself* and not the name of the function.  (In your code, you would have to access `function_name.func_name` to obtain the function's name, so I would suggest renaming `function_name` to `fn`, which is short for "function.")

You don't even need to declare predefined functions. You can use the `lambda` syntax to pass an anonymous callable on the fly:

```
# Instead of add_one, for example:
Calculator().calculate(lambda x: x + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially, fix your `__init__` so it doesn't complain when called with no args:

```
def __init__(self, prefix="hello")
```

use the function `__name__` in the call to `format` done in `calculate`:

```
msg = "executing {} function with {}"
print(msg.format(function_name.__name__, self.prefix))
```

then pass the function objects along:

```
Calculator().calculate(add_one)
# expect this to print:
# executing add_one function with hello
# 11


Calculator().calculate(minus_one)
# expect this to print:
# executing minus_one function with hello
# 9

Calculator().calculate(divide_in_half)
# expect this to print:
# executing divide_in_half function with hello
# 5
```

Comment: Thanks @Jim for the answer